# How to compare and print result using awk NR==FNR

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

I have 2 files. age2.txt & age3.txt
**age2.txt**

```
a=30  
b=23  
c=33  
d=43  
e=75
```

**age3.txt**

```
a=30  
b=26  
c=33  
d=44  
e=75
```

I need a command that :
compares the second column of both files and
print the line of first file (age2.txt) with " passed" if found matching or
print the line of first file (age2.txt) with " failed" if not matching

Expected output

```
a=30 passed  
b=23 failed  
c=33 passed  
d=43 failed  
e=75 passed
```

When I try it with awk, I see that for me the "failed" line repeats for both condition (notice for b=23 and d=43, it repeats..)

```
awk -F= 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$2;next}a[FNR]!=$2 {print $line " Failed" ;} a[FNR]=$2 {print $line " Passed" ;}' age2.txt age3.txt  
a=30 Passed  
b=26 Failed  
b=26 Passed  
c=33 Passed  
d=44 Failed  
d=44 Passed  
e=75 Passed
```

Can somebody please help to avoid repetition of the "failed" line?
Thank You in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need to add a `next` into `Failed`:

```
awk -F= 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$2;next}a[FNR]!=$2 {print $line " Failed" ;next} a[FNR]=$2 {print $line " Passed" ;}' age2.txt age3.txt
```

**Result:**

```
a=30 Passed
b=26 Failed
c=33 Passed
d=44 Failed
e=75 Passed
```

If you want to have the output reflect the value of the first file instead of the second then flip the positions of the input files:

```
age3.txt age2.txt
```

**Result:**

```
a=30 Passed
b=23 Failed
c=33 Passed
d=43 Failed
e=75 Passed
```

Comment: @I'L'l Thanks a ton! it worked. could you please give me a doc link for understanding NR==FNR better?

Answer (score 0):

Your awk can be simplified to this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} {print $1, ($1 in a) ? "passed":"failed"}' age3.txt age2.txt
a=30 passed
b=23 failed
c=33 passed
d=43 failed
e=75 passed
```

To compare only the 2nd column use:

```
awk -F= 'FNR==NR{a[$2]; next} {print $0, ($2 in a) ? "passed":"failed"}' age3.txt age2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibly simpler solution is to combine the two files with `paste`:

```
paste age2.txt age3.txt | awk -F'\t' '{print $1, $1==$2?"passed":"failed"}'
```

Comment: Thanks rici. great, this seems simple. However I face a small problem when the variable separator in both files are space ' ' instead of '='. For eg:  a 30  b 23  c 33  d 43... etc...In this example the comparison is always "failed"

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference if the variable separate is space, but it will fail if the variable separator is a tab character. It will also fail if the spacing is not consistent (sometimes one space, sometimes two), or if there are trailing spaces on the line. You'd need to look more closely at the files, basically.